# Tool to create recipe to preseed partitioning

Tags: ubuntu, partition, debian-installer, preseed

I want to preseed an Ubuntu 12.04 installer using a custom partitioning recipe. My disk layout is reasonably complex, and so is the recipe syntax itself. Hand-crafting such a recipe seems tedious and error prone.

Is there a tool to simply create a recipe from an existing disk, including its partitions and LVM configuration?

Answer (score 0):

I am not entirely sure about what you mean with "preseed". If you are talking about a KickStart or unattended install, one good tool for that is [anaconda](http://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Anaconda/Kickstart).

I have used it extensively for unattended installation of RedHatLinux. According to [Debian Wiki](https://wiki.debian.org/Anaconda) it is supported at Debian also. Being ubuntu a Debian derivative it should be usable.

You control the partitions with [command part](http://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Anaconda/Kickstart#part_or_partition).

The basic idea behind an unattended install is that you provide a [kickstart config file](http://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Anaconda/Kickstart#Creating_the_Kickstart_File) and anaconda does all the work.

Answer (score 0):

I have found no such tool and don't want to write one.  What I did was to treat the expert recipes as standard text files that I edit online with ACE editor.  Before sending the recipe to the preseed file in the mako template, I use this function to convert the text into a form ready for debconf.

https://github.com/umeboshi2/paella/blob/master/src/paella/paella/managers/util.py#L25

This function could be expanded to allow you to put comments in the recipe if it is complex enough to need that.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Kickstart.
An excerpt from https://gist.github.com/ludo/3652811 example:

```
bootloader --location=mbr
zerombr yes
clearpart --all --initlabel
part /boot --fstype=ext2 --size=64
part swap --size=1024
part / --fstype=ext4 --size=1 --grow
```

Answer (score 0):

Preseed is built into the Debian installer. Kickstart is a similar tool used with RHEL. I'm not aware of any tool like Red Hat's GUI system-config-kickstart tool or [Anaconda](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anaconda_(installer)) that allow you to graphically create the configuration file. If you often need to install Debian systems automatically (and maybe over the network) you might want to take a look at [FAI - Fully Automatic Installation](https://fai-project.org/) - it's features go beyond what preseed can do and it has pretty flexibly [partitioning capabilities](https://fai-project.org/doc/man/setup-storage.html).

---

But of course you can get the job done using preseed as well. The [Debian GNU/Linux Installation Guide](https://www.debian.org/releases/stable/installmanual) [says](https://www.debian.org/releases/stable/amd64/apbs03.en.html)

> The easiest way to create a preconfiguration file is to use the example file linked in [Section B.4, “Contents of the preconfiguration file (for buster)”](https://www.debian.org/releases/stable/amd64/apbs04.en.html) as basis and work from there.
>
> An alternative method is to do a manual installation and then, after rebooting, use the `debconf-get-selections` from the `debconf-utils` package to dump both the debconf database and the installer's cdebconf database to a single file:
>
> ```
> $ echo "#_preseed_V1" > file
> $ debconf-get-selections --installer >> file
> $ debconf-get-selections >> file
> ```
>
> However, a file generated in this manner will have some items that should not be preseeded, and the example file is a better starting place for most users.
>    To check possible values for questions, you can use `nano` to examine the files in `/var/lib/cdebconf` while an installation is in progress. View `templates.dat` for the raw templates and `questions.dat` for the current values and for the values assigned to variables.
>
> To check if the format of your preconfiguration file is valid before performing an install, you can use the command `debconf-set-selections -c preseed.cfg`.

If you have already completed the installation I would recommend to check `/var/log/installer` which might contains the information you need to create the preseed configuration.